# how to print arrayList as string in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am solving DFS problem so i used array of a ArrayList. Here is my code

```
ArrayList<Node> graph[] = new ArrayList[N+1];

         int u, v, w;
         for (int i = 1; i <=N; i++){
             graph[i] = new ArrayList<Node>();
       }

         for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++){

              u=sc.nextInt();
               v=sc.nextInt();
               w=sc.nextInt();


             graph[u].add(new Node(v,w));
             graph[v].add(new Node(u,w));

        }
System.out.println(graph[1].get(0));----------(1)
```

For above print statement i got output `Node@1db9742`.I don't know why i am getting this out.
My input:

```
1
3
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Plz help me on how to print exact output from array of arrayList

Edit: Node class:

```
class Node {
    static int i;
    int distance;

    Node(int i, int distance) {
        this.i = i;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Default inherited method `toString()` of Object class is being use to convert your node to String. Override `toString()` method in your Node class.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh: I sense a follow-up question coming...

Comment: Thanku @GurwinderSingh but still i got the same  output [Node@1db9742]

Comment: plz see my edit question @GurwinderSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to override the Node class' `toString()` method as per your needs.

For e.g - If you want only distance in text representation of your class, you can do something like -

```
class Node {
    static int i;
    int distance;

    Node(int i, int distance) {
        this.i = i;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(distance); // Change as per your needs
    }

}
```

---

More on this:

- http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/09/override-tostring-method-java-tips-example-code.html
- [Why to override toString Method inside DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468525/why-to-override-tostring-method-inside-dto)
- [How to override toString() properly in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You must override `toString` method for `Node` class, so `System.out.println()` method can use it to display what you are expecting. like this

```
class Node {
    static int i;
    int distance;

    Node(int i, int distance) {
        this.i = i;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node{" +
                "i=" + i + "," +
                "distance=" + distance +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh i got it i can't tick both the ans srry @GurwinderSingh

Comment: You should accept only the one answer  that solve your problem better, if you think the other answer is better, it's OK. Instead, you can upvote all the correct answers (after you get 20 reputations). Happy coding :)